# What is the best way to generate a condensed array like this in PHP?

Tags: php

I have an array like:

```
$arr[0] = ("1-3-2011","1","15"); //date(dd-mm-yyyy),id,amt
$arr[1] = ("1-4-2011","2","5");
$arr[2] = ("12-3-2011","6","20");
$arr[3] = ("1-3-2011","10","10");
$arr[4] = ("12-3-2011","3","10");
$arr[5] = ("1-4-2011","5","15");
$arr[6] = ("1-3-2011","7","15");
```

From this I need to generate a condensed array like

```
$newarr[0] = ("1-3-2011","1,7,10","40"); 
$newarr[0] = ("1-4-2011","2,5","20");
..
...
```

Basically the first one is a multidimentional array, containing date,id, and amount. In the new array, I need to condense the previous one for each unique date, ids as a csv string for duplicate dates, and amounts added.

What's the most efficient way to do this, performance wise?

Comment: The best would be to rework your query if this data is coming from a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
$newarr = array();

foreach($arr as $row) {
    if(!isset($newarr[$row[0]])) {
        $newarr[$row[0]] = array('ids' => array(), 'amount' => 0);
    }
    $newarr[$row[0]]['ids'][] = $row[1];
    $newarr[$row[0]]['amount'] += $row[2];
}

foreach($newarr as $key => &$row) {
    $row = array($key, implode(',', $row['ids']), $row['amount']);
} unset($row);
```

Working example:

> http://codepad.org/UmiDKLYJ

Comment: I think performance wise something like http://codepad.org/2Sf0wlz0 will be much better, less ugly and with correct keys.

Comment: Do you think that my answer was wrong or not useful or why the downvote? You shouldn't downvote an answer just because you think you have an better solution. Instead, post your solution as a new answer and let the post owner and community settle which one is better.

Comment: And considering performance, the difference between our solutions is negligible at least until there are millions of rows to consider. And what comes to ugliness, I'd reckon my answer is a lot more readable and less confusing.

Comment: Well, your answer is wrong - you left date keys in new array and it teachs bad algorithm practice - there is too much wrong with your code. And I think author wouldn't be asking for "performance wise" algorithm if he didn't have big arrays.